# Are there internationally published sources of trade sanctions?

Tags: international-trade, data-request, trading, sanctions

How to implement embargoes with respect to a trading company?

Let's assume i am a small trading agent which assists and guides small exporters and importers while keeping embargoes and light sanctions under considerations. My source of info regarding sanctions are workers of other big players. I usually get help from them in order to declare a trade clear.

I know that United Nations publishes Sanctions Lists of banned Individuals and Companies, I also know that Banks and Exchange companies have software solutions to screen a name against these lists.

These lists are not enough for Trading as an embargo usually includes source, destination and product being traded.

Are there any Internationally published sources of embargoes which can be consulted? Is there an automated software solution (free or cheap) to screening a trade?

Answer (score 1):

Try the WTO's [Trade Monitoring Database](https://tmdb.wto.org/en/explore).

Answer (score 0):

The following site might help you out: https://www.globaltradealert.org